# MPI_Init() crashes instantly on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: ubuntu, mpi, raspberry-pi4

Running a clean Ubuntu on a brand-new Raspberry Pi 4 Ubuntu,

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/mpi-hello-world/mpitutorial/tutorials/mpi-hello-world/code$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 5.4.0-1028-raspi #31-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Wed Jan 20 11:36:14 UTC 2021 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Just

`sudo apt install mpi mpich`

Make on this works fine:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  // Initialize the MPI environment. The two arguments to MPI Init are not
  // currently used by MPI implementations, but are there in case future
  // implementations might need the arguments.
  fprintf(stderr,"Starting...\n");
  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
  fprintf(stderr,"MPI_Init accomplished...\n");
  // Finalize the MPI environment. No more MPI calls can be made after this
  MPI_Finalize();
  fprintf(stderr,"MPI_Finalize done!\n");
}
```

but running it, instacrash when MPI_Initialize() is called.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/mpi-hello-world/mpitutorial/tutorials/mpi-hello-world/code$ mpirun -np 2 ./mpi_hello_world
Starting...
Starting...

===================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   PID 7855 RUNNING AT ubuntu
=   EXIT CODE: 139
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
===================================================================================
YOUR APPLICATION TERMINATED WITH THE EXIT STRING: Segmentation fault (signal 11)
This typically refers to a problem with your application.
Please see the FAQ page for debugging suggestions
```

Any suggestions?!?

Comment: First try `mpirun -np 2 hostname` to double check starting non MPI tasks work. You generally  need to install `mpich-dev` or something in order to build a MPI app, so `ldd mpi_hello_world` to confirm it is indeed using mpich and not an other library.

Comment: Mmm, different build/run libs sounds very plausible with both mpi and mpich installed.  And the hostname idea is a very good one to check, but as you can see from the "Starting..." messages it seems likely that the processes are getting forked correctly. Will check in the morning (I'm at home, the pile of 4s is at the office on a net I can't reach from here). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem was mixing mpi and mpich! This solved it:

```
sudo apt remove mpi mpich
sudo apt install mpi mpi-default-dev
```

After which `make` runs smoothly (which it did before), and then the execute also runs smoothly!

```
mpirun -np 2 ./mpi_hello_world
```

and all is good.
Thanks @Gilles for the hint.

(I picked mpi over mpich more or less at random, simple web searches don't show a clear reason to pick one or the other for the simple things we're planning to do.)

Comment: fwiw, I guess 'mpi' is a generic alias that is `openmpi` by default.